# how to add browser in my bot automation any where for capturing sites

Tags: automation, bots, capture, automationanywhere

I'm using latest version of automation anywhere and then I want to  capture the site elements.my problems is when I select the window for choosing browser it does not adding the browser and showing the error given below.

[ERROR PICTURES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNCnB.png)

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because your device does not have the agent installed or has an error.

[image]